# Query results in 13 results when using static text, and a null result set when the same value is inserted as a variable

Tags: mysql, python-3.4

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and Python 3.4, the the MySQL provided Python Connector. I'm new to Python.  So I think I'm still running into noob mistakes, but I can't figure this one out.

My program successfully connects with MySQL, and sets up a cursor, and it runs the following query with a result set of 13 rows.

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user= ...)


cursor = cnx.cursor()           
PortSQL ="""SELECT t1.CSI_ID, t2.Signal_Date, t2.NextGain 
FROM equity as t1 
INNER JOIN (equity_signal AS t2) 
ON (t2.equity_CSI_ID = t1.CSI_ID) 
WHERE YearWeek(t2.Signal_Date) = 201644 
    AND t2.currency_idCurrency = "USD"
    AND t1.UseEquity = 1 
    AND t1.NoData = 0 
    AND t2.SpikeShadow26 = 0 
    AND t1.Exchange IN ("NYSE","NASDAQ") 
    AND t2.EMA20Liquidity>500000 
    AND t2.StdDev50 < 0.02 
    AND (t2.CalcBool & 63) = 63 
ORDER BY (6*t2.LongBuy500 + 5*t2.LongBuy200 + 4*t2.LongBuy100 + 3*t2.MediumBuy50 + 2*t2.ShortBuy20 + 1*t2.ShortBuy10) 
DESC LIMIT 50"""

cursor.execute(PortSQL)
Results=cursor.fetchall()
```

When I attempt to drop in a variable for the Yearweek(t2.Signal_Date) = comparison, with the code sample as follows. I get a null set returned, and the following print output:

```
PortSQL ="""SELECT t1.CSI_ID, t2.Signal_Date, t2.NextGain 
FROM equity as t1 
INNER JOIN (equity_signal AS t2) 
ON (t2.equity_CSI_ID = t1.CSI_ID) 
WHERE YearWeek(t2.Signal_Date) = '%s' 
    AND t2.currency_idCurrency = "USD"
    AND t1.UseEquity = 1 
    AND t1.NoData = 0 
    AND t2.SpikeShadow26 = 0 
    AND t1.Exchange IN ("NYSE","NASDAQ") 
    AND t2.EMA20Liquidity>500000 
    AND t2.StdDev50 < 0.02 
    AND (t2.CalcBool & 63) = 63 
ORDER BY (6*t2.LongBuy500 + 5*t2.LongBuy200 + 4*t2.LongBuy100 + 3*t2.MediumBuy50 + 2*t2.ShortBuy20 + 1*t2.ShortBuy10) 
DESC LIMIT 50"""

print (PortSQL,(Yearweek[0]))
cursor.execute(PortSQL,(Yearweek[0]))
```

Here are the lines printed for the print (PortSQL,(Yearweek[0])) line.

```
SELECT t1.CSI_ID, t2.Signal_Date, t2.NextGain
FROM equity as t1
INNER JOIN (equity_signal AS t2)
ON (t2.equity_CSI_ID = t1.CSI_ID)
WHERE YearWeek(t2.Signal_Date) = '%s'
        AND t2.currency_idCurrency = "USD"
        AND t1.UseEquity = 1
        AND t1.NoData = 0
        AND t2.SpikeShadow26 = 0
        AND t1.Exchange IN ("NYSE","NASDAQ")
        AND t2.EMA20Liquidity>500000
        AND t2.StdDev50 < 0.02
        AND (t2.CalcBool & 63) = 63
ORDER BY (6*t2.LongBuy500 + 5*t2.LongBuy200 + 4*t2.LongBuy100 + 3*t2.MediumBuy50 + 2*t2.ShortBuy20 + 1*t2.ShortBuy10)
DESC LIMIT 50 201644
```

Comment: your second example isn't right... the sql doesn't have a `'%s'` in it.

Comment: Instead of `'%s'` should it be `%s` (no quote)?

Comment: I get a SQL error if I remove the single quotes around the %s.  mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s
AND t2.currency_idCurrency = "USD"
AND t1.UseEquity = 1
AND t1.NoData = 0